# Should the [sketch] and [sketch-3] tags be merged?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tagging, tag-synonyms

We have a decent amount of questions about Sketch, but there seem to be two separate tags: [sketch](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sketch) and [sketch-3](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sketch-3). The first has 27 questions, the other 18.

I am no Mac user and have never seen the program, let alone used it. Are these versions so significantly different that two tags are called for, or should we merge them?

Comment: I have zero objections to this, but I'll wait a bit before performing a merge to let others weigh in

Comment: ...and this makes me think: 'wy don't we have [tag: etch-a-sketch]?

Comment: "A bit" is now officially defined as 8+ months. Thanks go to plainclothes for reminding me that we forgot about this :)

Answer (score 4):

I havent used it but I wouldn't do any tag modification till someone can verify if there is a version difference that would cause the questions and answers to become invalid.  If there is no difference I am for deprecating the [sketch-3] tag and leaving one tag.

However, if there are multiple different versions we should try to find some more support from Sketch's community to help tag the questions accurately so the community can benefit from them.

I know in the past we've tried to reach out to similar program communities and they've treated us like it's a hostile take over.

It would be nice to have experts in the programs that are not Adobe to come along and make them better.

Answer (score 4):

There are some feature differences between sketch 2 and 3, but not enough to warrant version 3 to have its own tag, imho. We don't have tags for specific versions of other software, or do we?

I vote for a merge.

Comment: Yes, we do--the different adobe CS/CC version have their own tags.

Comment: Then I think it should be a general policy question. Either all software gets a per-version tag or none of them. It should not depend then on how much functionality has been added/changed between versions.

Comment: I disagree on the general policy thing. If there's hardly any difference between Sketch versions, then I'm all for merging, but the differences between Photoshop CS3 and Photoshop CC-2014 are too big too ignore. Unless the older versions' tags are relatively empty, that is.

Answer (score 1):

The tags [sketch](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sketch) and [sketch-3](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sketch-3) have been merged into [sketch-app](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sketch-app). There was one mistagged question related to "sketching", hence the "-app" distinction to prevent that from happening in the future (the url is http://sketchapp.com).